# Did one angel or multiple angels deliver news to Mary?

Tags: quran, tafseer, contradiction

> And as the **Angels** said, "O Maryam, (Mary) surely Allah has elected you and purified you and has elected you over the women of the worlds.
>
> **Dr. Ghali**  3:42

> Screening herself off from them. Then We sent to her Our **angel**, ˹Gabriel,˺ appearing before her as a man, perfectly formed.
>
> **Dr. Mustafa Khattab, the Clear Quran** 19:17

In verse 3:42 is mentioned that *angels* talked to Maryam talked (more than one).

But in verse 19:17 it is mentioned that *angle* talked to Maryam (one angle).

So can you explain this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be asking about these two verses regarding who talked to Mary:

> إذ قالت **الملائكة** يا مريم إن الله يبشرك بكلمة منه اسمه المسيح عيسى ابن مريم
>
> When the **angels** said, "O Mary, indeed Allah gives you good tidings of a word from Him, whose name will be the Messiah, Jesus, the son of Mary ..."
>
> <sup>— [Quran 3:45](http://quran.com/3/45)</sup>

> فأرسلنا إليها **روحنا** فتمثل لها بشرا سويا ... قال إنما أنا رسول ربك لأهب لك غلاما زكيا
>
> Then We sent to her Our **Spirit**, and he represented himself to her as a well-proportioned man ... He said, "I am only the messenger of your Lord to give you [news of] a pure boy."
>
> <sup>— [Quran 19:17-19](http://quran.com/19/17-19)</sup>

The spirit ( روح ) mentioned in the latter verse is Gabriel, who is among the angels and is their chief. The word angels ( الملائكة )  in the earlier verses also refers to him alone according to many exegetes.

That is because in Arabic language, a plural or genus can be used to refer to a single individual. There are many examples of this in the Quran, a few are as follows:

- Plurals are used throughout the Quran for Allah, while He is one.

  > إنا نحن نزلنا الذكر وإنا له لحافظون
  >
  > Indeed, it is We who sent down the Qur'an and indeed, We will be its guardians
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 15:9](http://quran.com/15/9)</sup>
- Messengers ( رسل ) is used, while what is meant is one prophet:

  > يا أيها الرسل كلوا من الطيبات واعملوا صالحا
  >
  > O messengers {i.e. Muhammad or Jesus}, eat from the good foods and work righteousness.
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 23:51](http://quran.com/23/51)</sup>

  > وقوم نوح لما كذبوا الرسل
  >
  > And the people of Noah - when they denied the messengers {i.e. Noah}
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 25:37](http://quran.com/25/37)</sup>
- People ( الناس ) is used, while what is meant is one individual:

  > الذين قال لهم الناس إن الناس قد جمعوا لكم فاخشوهم
  >
  > Those to whom people {i.e. Nuaym ibn Masud} said, "Indeed, the people have gathered against you, so fear them."
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 3:173](http://quran.com/3/173)</sup>

  > أم يحسدون الناس على ما آتاهم الله من فضله فقد آتينا آل إبراهيم الكتاب والحكمة
  >
  > Or do they envy people {i.e. Muhammad} for what Allah has given them of His bounty? But we had already given the family of Abraham the Scripture and wisdom
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 4:54](http://quran.com/4/54)</sup>
- Mosques ( مساجد ) is used, while what is meant is one specific mosque:

  > ما كان للمشركين أن يعمروا مساجد
  >
  > It is not for the polytheists to maintain the mosques { i.e. Masjid al-Haram}
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 9:17](http://quran.com/9/17)</sup>

Another possible explanation is that the news was given twice to Mary, once by a group of angels and once by Gabriel alone - so the two verses mention two separate events.

---

**Reference:**

> وجائز في العربية أن يخبر عن الواحد بلفظ الجمع
>
> It is valid in Arabic to give news of one person with a plural word
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura3-aya39.html)</sup>